How to write reliable module augmentations using Typescript?
I have a package which is shared among other packages in my project:
export class User {
    constructor(
        public id: string;
        public email: string;
        public name: string;
    ){}
}

in my other package where I use this I've added an augmentation:
// src/mapper.ts
declare module "@shared/types" {
    namespace User {
        let test: () => User;
    }
}

and an implementation too:
// src/mapper.ts
User.test= (...) =>
    new User({
        id: "test",
        email: "test@test.com",
        name: "test"
    });

My problem is that if I use this elsewhere in my app:
// src/elsewhere.ts
console.log(`User.test is: ${User.test}`);

this will print undefined. The project builds properly and I can't see errors in VS Code either. What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure that these augmentations are properly loaded and I get a compiler error if not?
